# Why does my method print an empty list?

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, binary-tree

I'm trying to print a tree level by level in an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result`. Each list in `result` is considered its own level.

Example:

```
         1                
        / \             
       2   3   
      / \ / \           
     4  5 6  7
==>  [1][2, 3][4, 5, 6, 7]
```

For some reason, I keep getting back an empty list. Here is my code:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> printLevelByLevel(TreeNode root) {
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
  ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  if(root == null) return result;
  int levelCount = 0;
  Queue<TreeNode> q = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
  q.add(root);
  while(true){
    levelCount = q.size();
    if(levelCount == 0) break;
    while(levelCount > 0){
        TreeNode curr = q.poll();
        temp.add(curr.data);
        if(curr.left != null){
            q.add(curr.left);
        }
        if(curr.right != null){
            q.add(curr.right);
        }
        levelCount--;
    } // end of inner while 
    result.add(temp);
    temp.clear();
  } // end of outter while loop 

 return result;
}
```

is my temp.clear() right? I try putting it in different places but still the same result. I know I can do this with two `Queues` but I want to be able to do it with one `Queue`.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, temp.clear() is problematic. Try to replace "result.add(temp);" with "result.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));"

Comment: @Ran it worked, thanks. BTW, I'm curious if I clear temp after adding to the result list, why do I get an empty list. Shouldn't everything in temp be added to result before being cleared?

Comment: It is indeed added to the result, and then cleared... You are not adding a list of numbers to result - you are adding temp. So if you clear temp, you clear result. So you need a new list to result, based on temp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the same `ArrayList` instance (referenced by the `temp` variable) to your `reuslt` list multiple times is wrong, since your `result` will contain multiple empty lists (or, more accurately, multiple references to the same empty list) at the end.

You should create a new instance in each iteration instead of clearing the single instance references by `temp`:

```
while(true){
    levelCount = q.size();
    if(levelCount == 0) break;
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while(levelCount > 0){
        TreeNode curr = q.poll();
        temp.add(curr.data);
        if(curr.left != null){
            q.add(curr.left);
        }
        if(curr.right != null){
            q.add(curr.right);
        }
        levelCount--;
    } // end of inner while 
    result.add(temp);
}
```